# Visualization of affinity (adjacency) matrix

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matrix, graph, visualization

I constructed a graph based on similarity of adjacent superpixels on an image and consequently I computed its corresponding adjacency (affinity) matrix.    I saw several [instances](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Pichao_Wang/publication/325787961_Saliency_Detection_via_Affinity_Graph_Learning_and_Weighted_Manifold_Ranking/links/5ca54eeb458515f785222a0b/Saliency-Detection-via-Affinity-Graph-Learning-and-Weighted-Manifold-Ranking.pdf) of visualization of such matrices as in the following figure.

[image]

Is this some type of clustering and how producing such a representation is possible in MATLAB? Is there any specific function or method for that?

**Update (Finding):** As @Yuval Harpaz suggested, I found that it is some type of Spectral clustering and there is a specific [Matlab function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/spectralcluster.html) for that. Now, the question is how to represent spectral clustering results similar to the OP.

Comment: Can you attack a relevant source ( in the form of an article )?

Comment: @Mano, a link to the article added.

Comment: take a look here https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/26354-spectral-clustering-algorithms

Comment: @YuvalHarpaz, Thanks for the suggestion. As you suggested it's spectral clustering. https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/spectralcluster.html. The question is how to represent the result that produced in the above link as in the OP.

Comment: So you already have the affinity matrix and you just want to see it as an image? Honestly, that's not what I understood from your original question. See [`image`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/image.html), [`imagesc`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imagesc.html?s_tid=doc_ta) and [`pcolor`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/pcolor.html?s_tid=doc_ta).

Comment: As  @beaker says, the second figure in your question is likely `imagesc(matrix); axis off`. Is that what you want?

Comment: And maybe play around a little bit with `colormap`.

Comment: You should post some preliminary code here, taking an image such as peppers.png, break it to superpixels, try to implement affinity and let us help to improve your code. Otherwise we'd have to read the paper and write the code from scratch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily visualize the matrix using `imagesc(Affinity_Matrix);`

Likely you want the axis off `axis off` and you may want to change the colormap with `colormap(parula)` or some of the other available colormap.

Finally, if you want to avoid showing the center diagonal values, you can replace them with zeroes.

You can do that with `Affinity_Matrix(eye(size(Affinity_Matrix))==1)=0;`

Basically create an identity matrix of the same size and make zero where this identity matrix is one.

Comment: Using "Affinity_Matrix(eye(size(Affinity_Matrix))==1)=0; " the diagonal line was not removed! In fact nothing is changed. Any idea?

Comment: @Eilia absolutely no idea, as that code does exactly what I said. It makes the diagonal to have zero as value. Its unambiguous.

Comment: Thanks anyway. I'm working on the issue and will comment the solution here!